# which of these approach is better using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page wherein I have 6 menu items to the left and have to display their respective contents on the left (based on choice AND on the `click()` event).

**Approach 1:**

I can `switch()` the `id`'s of the menu items and dynamically `append()` their respective content on the right.

(writing code on the fly, please excuse any errors)

like so,

```
switch(id)
{
    case 1: $(".ContentRight").children().remove();
            $(".ContentRight").append('<img src="someImage1" .../>');
            break;

    case 2: $(".ContentRight").children().remove();
            $(".ContentRight").append('<img src="someImage2" .../>');
            break;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Although, this seems to be a more costly option as compared to

**Approach 2 :** loading all the content at first (with a `display:none` or something) and then displaying the content based on the choice.

However, for the 2nd approach, is it "fine" to load contents the user may not even see?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to append the image associated with the id to the `ContentRight` on hover or click or something like that? Btw, id's can't be a number unless you're using html5 exclusively.

Comment: yes, not only an image, can be something else as well. I'll `parseInt` the `ids` if anything ;-)

Comment: in such cases I usually choose the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon several factors:

1. How many of these images are there and how large are they.  If there are a ton and they are sizable and a given user will only ever see a couple of them, then it may be a lot more efficient for everyone to only load the ones that are actually needed when they are needed (option 1).
2. If you need an image to display promptly when your code wants to make it visible, then that image must be preloaded already, otherwise there will be a delay for the image to load when you make it visible.   So, this instant type of performance requires that an image be loaded before it's needed (option 2).
3. Loading them all ahead of time and just hiding/showing the desired image is usually a lot simpler code.  If nothing else is driving the decision, go with simplicity every time (option 2).
4. If the user is likely to eventually see all the images, then you may as well preload them all (option 2).
5. If you're trying to optimize for small memory devices or expensive bandwidth (e.g. phones), then you will want to only load images that are actually going to be needed (option 1).
6. If the images will be needed in a predefined order, then there is a hybrid approach.  You load the current image and preload the next image so it's instantly ready.  When you display the next image, you then preload the next one after that.  In this way, you always have the next image ready to go, but you don't preload more than one ahead so minimize bandwidth and memory usage.  I've written an HTML5 slideshow that works this way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with option 2.  It's the cleanest and if you are planning on this being a public web page it's indexable by the search engines.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

the second choice is more appropriate.

the problem of the option 1 is processing the DOM frequently. constant [reflow and repaint](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/) (the moving and reprinting the layout) of the page is a costly process in a browser. imagine you took the following steps after picking the choice:

1. remove elements from the DOM
2. recalculated the layout (affecting other elements layout)
3. added elements in the DOM
4. recalculated the layout

the second one is just showing and hiding. you didn't remove elements. it's just like only doing steps 2 and 4!

Answer (score 0):

The first approach downloads only what is needed but the second approach downloads all the items at the beginning at once and uses them when needed.

If you display items based on hover event, it is good to use the second approach because people don't wait while hovering.

If you display items based on a click event, most probably people who click will wait for something to happen, so you have time to load that  (which could be further enhanced using a preloader). In this scenario, the first approach seems to be better because it saves bandwidth provided you create an element in the DOM on first load and hide it when not in need.

Also, as @Michael Rice says, the second approach would help for better search engine indexing of your items if the Search Bots can read Javascript (like GOOGLE-BOT)

It's up to you now. Your implementation should reflect your needs.

Answer (score 0):

do both:

```
function LoadContent(id) {
    var active = $('#'+id);
    $('.added').hide(); // hide all
    if (active.length) {
        active.show();  // if it's already been loaded, just show
    } else {
        active = $('<div></div>').attr('id', id).addClass('added');
        active.load('url to get new content');   // load it dynamically
        $('.contentRight').append(active);
    }
}
```